# Error occurred in Spring boot + Gradle + Oracle jdbc + jsp project

Tags: oracle, java

[image]

I'm doing Spring boot project, and I'm trying to add dependencies which are ojdbc8 and tomcat-embed-jasper. ojdbc8 library is for connecting Oracle database by using Hikari, and tomcat-embed-jasper is for using jsp. However It seems like these two libraries get problem when I use them in same time. I've continuously clicked Refresh Gradle Project, but It doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the error..

[image]

java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at com.example.react.ReactApplication.main(ReactApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor20.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.oracle.database.jdbc\ojdbc8\21.1.0.0\50044485aea10afd7defeee8109c5195b4d3cae2\oraclepki.jar
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1843) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1198) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:701) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:240) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:171) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:347) ~[na:na]
... 52 common frames omitted

Comment: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.oracle.database.jdbc\ojdbc8\21.1.0.0\50044485aea10afd7defeee8109c5195b4d3cae2\oraclepki.jar.   A problem with dependencies or their order?